# Print which of a list of input terms has no occurances in files?

Tags: command-line

I have a file containing my search terms such as:

```
term1
term2
term3
```

I want to see which of these strings do not appear in any file in the current directory.

So if term1 and term2 occurred in files but term3 did not, the command would simply print:

```
term3
```

Basically finding which of a list of input terms don't occur in text config files in the current directory.

Comment: Do you mean you want to test every file and find out which files do not contain all the search terms?

Comment: No I want to test each search term and find out which search terms are not contained in any of the files in the current working directory.

Comment: Are the files smallish?  Are they text files?

Comment: Yes they are a few KB each, total around 840KB, if that is smallish.

Comment: Yes they are text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  It should create `notfound.txt` with any search terms from a file called `c:\fileterms.txt` that it doesn't find.

```
@echo off
del notfound.txt 2>nul
copy /a *.* tmp.bin.tmp >nul
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' type "C:\fileterms.txt" ') do (
find "%%a" < tmp.bin.tmp >nul || echo %%a
)>>notfound.txt
del tmp.bin.tmp
```

Comment: Code was edited to fix a bug where it didn't append to the file.